# Maintaining same number of digits in Excel file when converting to table in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, table, excel

I have two fields containing lat and long values which are precise up to 8 digits. When I use the excel to table tool, Arc removes the last two digits in both fields leaving me with lat and long fields with only 6 digits.

How do I convert to a table in ArcGIS 10.2 and maintain the same number of decimal places as in my original excel file?

Comment: I am not seeing this problem with 10.3. Can you try saving your excel file to a CSV and then export the CSV as a table

Comment: Check the display of the field in ArcGIS. It may be the default display is 6 decimal places.

Comment: And 6 digits is good to ~10cm. What sort of data is this?

Comment: In addition to checking the display, what data type is the field in the table that the tool is creating? It would have to be a double to store that precision, and I know sometimes when just adding spreadsheets Arc incorrectly identifies the necessary data type.